# How to convert json array to json object in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json array like in the below image:

[JSon array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8fun.png)

I want it to be onyl json object and not array. Like when I do JSON.stringify I get this: `[{"total_exec_qty":"286595","total_notional":"21820771.72","total_wt_arr_last_slp":"2.4364","total_num_ords":"1630","total_wt_ivwap_slp":"6.0969","total_wt_arr_slp":"1.7889","total_ord_qty":"576991"}]`

But I only want it like this: `{"total_exec_qty":"286595","total_notional":"21820771.72","total_wt_arr_last_slp":"2.4364","total_num_ords":"1630","total_wt_ivwap_slp":"6.0969","total_wt_arr_slp":"1.7889","total_ord_qty":"576991"}`

How do I get that?

UPDATE: Doing this right now already:

```
var json_temp = JSON.stringify(json4);
    console.log("json_temp")
    console.log(json_temp);
    var json_temp1 = json_temp[0];
    console.log("json temp1");
    console.log(json_temp1);
```

But getting the following in console.log:
[Getting this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4V8G.png)

Comment: Do `JSON.stringify(myArray[0])`?

Comment: JSON.parse(array[0])

Comment: @ram  
     
Please see my update above. I'm doing that already but getting weird output on console.log

Comment: @Natasha its not weird but its not what you have in your example at all. The data you have coming in is an array of arrays and in that situation we must know what you want to do with the data when there are multiple sets.

Comment: @JustinHerter there will never be any more sets of data other that what I've shown. Data will always be in the form (only values will differ): [{"total_exec_qty":"286595","total_notional":"21820771.72","total_wt_arr_last_slp":"2.4364","total_num_ords":"1630","total_wt_ivwap_slp":"6.0969","total_wt_arr_slp":"1.7889","total_ord_qty":"576991"}] and I want it to be in the form: {"total_exec_qty":"286595","total_notional":"21820771.72","total_wt_arr_last_slp":"2.4364","total_num_ords":"1630","total_wt_ivwap_slp":"6.0969","total_wt_arr_slp":"1.7889","total_ord_qty":"576991"}

Comment: i.e.,  json_temp will always be [{"total_exec_qty":"286595","total_notional":"21820771.72","total_wt_arr_last_slp":"2.4364","total_num_ords":"1630","total_wt_ivwap_slp":"6.0969","total_wt_arr_slp":"1.7889","total_ord_qty":"576991"}]

Comment: @Natasha in the screenshot it shows [array[1], array[1]] which means you have an array, with two arrays inside each of which contain one item. so if you just want the first one of each you could just do "array[0][0]" but again that will only get you the first array first item.

Comment: But I have already converted that to json_temp right? Now I want to work with json_temp. Why do you need extra information with which I don't want to work?

Comment: changing the screenshot and editing your original question is really destroying the context of this conversation for someone that may need the same help you are looking for. the answers you seek are already here. just try them. Good luck

Comment: I never changed the question. I was already doing what the answer says, but that isn't working. I still want to extract json object from the json array.

Answer (score 1):

just reference the object like this:

```
var array = [{"total_exec_qty":"286595","total_notional":"21820771.72","total_wt_arr_last_slp":"2.4364","total_num_ords":"1630","total_wt_ivwap_slp":"6.0969","total_wt_arr_slp":"1.7889","total_ord_qty":"576991"}];

var object = array[0];
```

Alternatively you could copy the object and reassign it to the same variable like the following, note: This second method is a bit more expensive.

```
var data = [{"total_exec_qty":"286595","total_notional":"21820771.72","total_wt_arr_last_slp":"2.4364","total_num_ords":"1630","total_wt_ivwap_slp":"6.0969","total_wt_arr_slp":"1.7889","total_ord_qty":"576991"}];

data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data[0]));
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/wps1q3zo/1/) is a working example.

Comment: Please see my update above. I'm doing that already but getting weird output on console.log

Comment: @Natasha your data is an array of arrays and thats why its not working for you. You have multiple datasets coming in so what do you want to do with them?

Comment: I have update the answer with two working examples hope this helps