# How can i fetch data from an array in json object?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I want to fetch the values in the List array from the json object.

Here is my JS / Ajax code:

```
 $.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/sort_api/" + a,
   contentType: 'application/json',
   dataType: 'json', //specify jsonp
   success: function(data) {
     var htmlData= '';
     for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
       htmlData+= '<li>'+data[i]+' </li>';
     }
     $('#list').html(htmlData);
     // alert(list);
     console.log(data);
   }.bind(this),
     error: function(e) {
       console.log('error', e);
     }
   });
```

Here is the console log(data) result:

```
 {status: "200", status_message: "List Sorted", List: Array(5)}
 List:(5) ["Abc", "Take 78A", "Take Airport", "Take flight", "Take flight"]
 status:"200"
 status_message:"List Sorted"
```

When i write `console.log(data['status'])` 
It shows the value 200 in console

But when i write `console.log(data['list']);`
it shows undefined

Can somebody tell me what i am missing?
I want to retrieve the array(List) in that object

Comment: console.log(data.List); try this

Comment: Did you try `console.log(data['List'])`? Its case sensitive

Comment: Yo have to do this: `data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data[0]));`. And you have the same issue in this [*LINK*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40308802/how-to-convert-json-array-to-json-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with **each**

```
$.each(data, function( index, value ) {
  htmlData+= '<li>'+value+' </li>';
});
```

Answer (score -1):

try in capital **List** not **list**

```
console.log(data.List)
```

or

```
console.log(data['List'])
```

both will work.

Comment: do you think, is it required to answer this question. @zeropublix and me already commented this

Comment: The question should be closed because it's a basically the result of a typo.